# geolocation permission doesn't work with Manifest Version 3 Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, geolocation, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to develop an Chrome Extension which would be compatible with Manifest Version 3, but I run into problem with getting current user's geolocation coordinates, which works with Manifest Version 2, but for Manifest Version 3 it throws that `navigator.geolocation` is undefined.

Here are my manifest.json and background.js files:

manifest.json:

```
    "name": "Chrome Extension MV3",
    "description": "Learning all about Chrome Extensions Manifest Version 3!",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["geolocation"]
}
```

background.js:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    console.log(latitude, longitude);
});
```

Comment: Add a comment in https://crbug.com/169271 and also in https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/72

Answer (score 0):

Exact same thing is happening to me.

Works fine in chrome f12 console just not in extension i get the exact same error.

```
var getlocale = function() {
  var geoSuccess = function(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);
  };
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
};
```